# what's the best way to chainload this

Tags: boot-loader

I have two disks. 
One contains windows and is a SATA-drive. 
The other one contains Foresight Linux and is a IDE-drive.
Now I have installed extlinux as the bootloader for Foresight Linux.

Now I want to chainload it with the windows bootloader so I can  boot both.
In the bios I can only choose the SATA-drive to boot.

Can this be working and if so, how can I do this.
I tried to use Easybsd but then the only thing I can see is boot error.

Answer (score 1):

Is there a reason why you'd want to use the Windows bootloader specifically? If you install grub or syslinux on the SATA drive, you can create a menuentry for the Windows as well as the Linux systems--actually, other OS-bootloaders are, in most cases, automatically detected and configured. Otherwise, if you still prefer to stick with the Windows bootloader you might want to look for a solution on their websites...something like msdn.

Comment: you might be able to use a third-party software like [EasyBCD](http://neosmart.net/wiki/display/EBCD/EasyBCD+Documentation+Home)

Comment: Like I said I did try easybcd but that one seems not to be able to boot extlinux. I get Always a boot error.

Comment: @RoelofWobben, you boot linux directly, skipping extlinux.